# MySql select by score desc - when there are multiple score totals.... ODD

Tags: php, mysql

ok, so I have a table filled with client "testimonials". Some are marked out of 10, and others are out of 5. (they come from different sources)

My table has the following fields:

```
id (int 4 ) AI Pri Index
headline varchar 255
content text
source varchar 55
score double
```

So my problem is this:

```
SELECT * from testimonials WHERE score > 8 ORDER BY rand()
```

this works perfectly for my main set of testimonials scored out of 10, but now I have a new set that are marked out of 5, I need to devise a new way to pull these out too and put them in the mix.

So far I have removed the score > 8 clause, and added a SWITCH limit clause in my script to remove <8 for source 1, and < 3 for source2.

These are now shown in order DESC, but I want the whole lot to be randomized, or at the least source1 and source2 all mixed together in the result.

I would prefer to do all this in the Query...
Any ideas?

Comment: just a suggestion, why not use percentages, stuff from source 1, divide by 10 and get percentage and those of source 2, divide by 5 and get percentages, then you'll have both of them in terms of percentages and you can treat it as the same.

Comment: using the source and score get a percentage column and then use that for sorting and randomizing. if source is 1 percentage = 10/score else percentage = 5/score.

Comment: to randomise the results, you could use ORDER BY uuid().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a simple OR condition to your working query:

```
SELECT * from testimonials WHERE score > 8 OR (source = 'source2' AND score > 3) ORDER BY rand()
```

This selects scores > 8 for source1 and > 3 for source2 as your SWITCH explanation suggests.

Comment: Simple! Nice answer, did exactly whats needed.

Answer (score 4):

Add a column with the value of a rating max - called max_score below.  So in your case its either 5 or 10.  Then normalize using a percentage:

```
 SELECT * from testimonials WHERE (score/max_score) > 0.8 ORDER BY rand()
```

Easy.

Comment: BTW - order by rand() - rand() being the problem, will perform terribly as the  source data grows.  Consider instead a pseudo-randomizer to order by instead since I'm guessing you just don't want it to seem like the same testimonial appears every time.  If you have a primary key you can add a random integer to and then modulo and order by that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about normalizing on the spot according to `source`? Then you don't have to add another field:

```
SELECT source, score FROM testimonial WHERE (score/IF(source='1',10,5)) >= .8;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d2bdf/8)

This assumes that `source` can be either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate by source. Either inline for known sources

```
SELECT score, 
CASE source
   WHEN 1 THEN 10
   WHEN 2 THEN 5 ...
END CASE as max_score
FROM testimonials
WHERE (score/max_score*10) > 8
ORDER BY rand()
```

Or create a source table and join them

```
SELECT t.score, 
s.max_score
FROM testimonials t
LEFT JOIN source_table s
  ON s.source=t.source
WHERE (t.score/s.max_score*10) > 8
ORDER BY rand()
```